# getting extra edge when removing the edges connected to the source vertex in a graph

Tags: c++, graph

last week i posted a code to calculate the shortest path in a graph using Dijkastra algorithm but it was very long and nobody was interesting in reading it completely so i deleted it, and now i am trying to simplify the code by going part by part, the code isn't complete yet, and i will cut part of the code here to focus on the first problem that i am facing so far.

briefly i have a class Graph it is going to be constructed by two other classes a vector of elements are instances of a class Edge , and another vector of elements of class Vertex , every vertex has an id , and every edge has two vertices and weight .

class Graph has a method its name is shortest takes two vertices as arguments the first one for the source of the graph and the second is for the destination.

So far i am trying to eliminate the edges that are connected to the source vertex , but i am getting an extra edge still in the vector edges it is connected to the source while all the other edges related to the source are removed.

to demonstrate the result , i initialized a graph has five vertices vers[0], vers[1], vers[2], vers[3], vers[4], and there are 10 edges connecting those vertices starting from eds[0], eds[1], ....eds[9].

the source vertex is vers[2] is connected by 4 edges , so when applying the method shortest as it is shown in the code below i should get rid of all those 4 edges and end with 6 edges , but the result was that i got rid of 3 edges and i have 7 edges remained, the result is as follows:

```
Hello, This is a graph
0____1     5
0____3     4
0____4     6
1____3     5
1____4     7
2____4     8
3____4     3
size of edges 7
size of vertices 5
```

as you can notice , there still an edge connected to the source which is 2 , the problem is in this edge (by the way 8 is the weight of the edge)

```
2____4     8
```

there is something wrong in the method shortest and specifically in the for loop , i hope you can help in finding my mistake.

Thanks in advance.
Here is the code

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include <stdlib.h>   // for rand()
using namespace std;

const unsigned int N = 5;

class Vertex
{
 private:
     unsigned int id;                 // the name of the vertex  
public:   
    unsigned int get_id(){return id;};
    void set_id(unsigned int value) {id = value;};

    Vertex(unsigned int init_val = 0) :id (init_val){}      // constructor   
    ~Vertex() {};                                           // destructor
};


class Edge
{
  private:
    Vertex first_vertex;                 // a vertex on one side of the edge
    Vertex second_vertex;                // a vertex on the other side of the edge
    unsigned int weight;                 // the value of the edge ( or its weight )     
  public:   
    unsigned int get_weight() {return weight;};
    void set_weight(unsigned int value) {weight = value;};

    Vertex get_ver_1(){return first_vertex;};
    Vertex get_ver_2(){return second_vertex;};

    void set_first_vertex(Vertex v1) {first_vertex = v1;};
    void set_second_vertex(Vertex v2) {second_vertex = v2;};


    Edge(const Vertex& vertex_1 = 0, const Vertex& vertex_2 = 0, unsigned int init_weight = 0)
    : first_vertex(vertex_1), second_vertex(vertex_2), weight(init_weight)
     {
     }  


    ~Edge() {} ; // destructor

};


class Graph
{
private:
     std::vector<Vertex>   vertices;
     std::vector<Edge>   edges;  


public:
     Graph(vector<Vertex> ver_vector, vector<Edge> edg_vector)
    : vertices(ver_vector), edges(edg_vector){}

     ~Graph() {}

     vector<Vertex> get_vertices(){return vertices;}
     vector<Edge> get_edges(){return edges;}

     void set_vertices(vector<Vertex> vector_value) {vertices = vector_value;}
     void set_edges(vector<Edge> vector_ed_value) {edges = vector_ed_value;}

     unsigned int shortest(Vertex src, Vertex dis);


};



unsigned int Graph::shortest(Vertex src, Vertex dis) {
        vector<Vertex> ver_out;
        vector<Edge> track;

        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < edges.size(); ++i)
            {
                if((edges[i].get_ver_1().get_id() == src.get_id()) || (edges[i].get_ver_2().get_id() == src.get_id()))
                    {
                    track.push_back (edges[i]);

                    if(edges[i].get_ver_1().get_id() == src.get_id())
                        {ver_out.push_back (edges[i].get_ver_1());}
                    else
                        {ver_out.push_back (edges[i].get_ver_2());}

                    edges.erase(edges.begin() + i ); //****
                    }
            };


    }





int main()
{
cout<< "Hello, This is a graph"<< endl;

vector<Vertex> vers(5);
vers[0].set_id(0);
vers[1].set_id(1);
vers[2].set_id(2);
vers[3].set_id(3);
vers[4].set_id(4);

vector<Edge> eds(10);
eds[0].set_first_vertex(vers[0]);
eds[0].set_second_vertex(vers[1]);
eds[0].set_weight(5);   

eds[1].set_first_vertex(vers[0]);
eds[1].set_second_vertex(vers[2]);
eds[1].set_weight(9);

eds[2].set_first_vertex(vers[0]);
eds[2].set_second_vertex(vers[3]);
eds[2].set_weight(4);

eds[3].set_first_vertex(vers[0]);
eds[3].set_second_vertex(vers[4]);
eds[3].set_weight(6);

eds[4].set_first_vertex(vers[1]);
eds[4].set_second_vertex(vers[2]);
eds[4].set_weight(2);

eds[5].set_first_vertex(vers[1]);
eds[5].set_second_vertex(vers[3]);
eds[5].set_weight(5);

eds[6].set_first_vertex(vers[1]);
eds[6].set_second_vertex(vers[4]);
eds[6].set_weight(7);

eds[7].set_first_vertex(vers[2]);
eds[7].set_second_vertex(vers[3]);
eds[7].set_weight(1);

eds[8].set_first_vertex(vers[2]);
eds[8].set_second_vertex(vers[4]);
eds[8].set_weight(8);

eds[9].set_first_vertex(vers[3]);
eds[9].set_second_vertex(vers[4]);
eds[9].set_weight(3);


unsigned int path;

Graph graf(vers, eds);
path = graf.shortest(vers[2], vers[4]);


cout<<graf.get_edges()[0].get_ver_1().get_id() <<"____"<<graf.get_edges()[0].get_ver_2().get_id() <<"     "<<graf.get_edges()[0].get_weight()<< endl;  //test
cout<<graf.get_edges()[1].get_ver_1().get_id() <<"____"<<graf.get_edges()[1].get_ver_2().get_id() <<"     "<<graf.get_edges()[1].get_weight()<< endl;  //test
cout<<graf.get_edges()[2].get_ver_1().get_id() <<"____"<<graf.get_edges()[2].get_ver_2().get_id() <<"     "<<graf.get_edges()[2].get_weight()<< endl;  //test
cout<<graf.get_edges()[3].get_ver_1().get_id() <<"____"<<graf.get_edges()[3].get_ver_2().get_id() <<"     "<<graf.get_edges()[3].get_weight()<< endl;  //test
cout<<graf.get_edges()[4].get_ver_1().get_id() <<"____"<<graf.get_edges()[4].get_ver_2().get_id() <<"     "<<graf.get_edges()[4].get_weight()<< endl;  //test
cout<<graf.get_edges()[5].get_ver_1().get_id() <<"____"<<graf.get_edges()[5].get_ver_2().get_id() <<"     "<<graf.get_edges()[5].get_weight()<< endl;  //test
cout<<graf.get_edges()[6].get_ver_1().get_id() <<"____"<<graf.get_edges()[6].get_ver_2().get_id() <<"     "<<graf.get_edges()[6].get_weight()<< endl;  //test
//cout<<graf.get_edges()[7].get_ver_1().get_id() <<"____"<<graf.get_edges()[7].get_ver_2().get_id() <<"     "<<graf.get_edges()[7].get_weight()<< endl;  //test
//cout<<graf.get_edges()[8].get_ver_1().get_id() <<"____"<<graf.get_edges()[8].get_ver_2().get_id() <<"     "<<graf.get_edges()[8].get_weight()<< endl;  //test
//cout<<graf.get_edges()[9].get_ver_1().get_id() <<"____"<<graf.get_edges()[9].get_ver_2().get_id() <<"     "<<graf.get_edges()[9].get_weight()<< endl;  //test


cout<<"size of edges"<<graf.get_edges().size()<< endl;
cout<<"size of vertices"<<graf.get_vertices().size()<< endl;

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are effectively skipping some vector elements in your `Graph::shortest` for loop because you are incrementing `i` even when you `erase` current element. Change it to something like this to fix the problem:

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < edges.size();) { // no ++i here
    if ((edges[i].get_ver_1().get_id() == src.get_id()) || (edges[i].get_ver_2().get_id() == src.get_id())) {
        track.push_back(edges[i]);

        if (edges[i].get_ver_1().get_id() == src.get_id()) {
            ver_out.push_back(edges[i].get_ver_1());
        } else {
            ver_out.push_back(edges[i].get_ver_2());
        }

        edges.erase(edges.begin() + i);
    } else {
        ++i; // increment only if not erasing
    }
}
```

Alternatively as per comment, using iterators:

```
for (auto i = edges.begin(); i != edges.end();) {
    if ((i->get_ver_1().get_id() == src.get_id()) || (i->get_ver_2().get_id() == src.get_id())) {
        track.push_back(*i);

        if (i->get_ver_1().get_id() == src.get_id()) {
            ver_out.push_back(i->get_ver_1());
        } else {
            ver_out.push_back(i->get_ver_2());
        }

        i = edges.erase(i);
    } else {
        i++;
    }
}
```

You are also missing a `return` statement in that function.

Comment: Better still, use an iterator.

Comment: @user2802841 , you got a very subtle point , i tried your code and it looks good so far , now i will continue writing the original code and see how it will develop , but for now i really appreciate your help.